# How to signal the Java FX main thread from an event handler?

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency, event-handling

I was working on a chess game application and I decided to make the main game loop wait until the user selects a field. To do this, I made a `java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition` object, on which the main Application Thread waits and which is signaled by the event handler once the user has clicked somewhere.

However, the click handler is never run, and as such, the entire program is frozen, since the condition is never signaled. Is there some way to make sure that the handler is run, or are events just not checked while the main thread is waiting on a condition?

(Almost) minimal example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

public class EventHandlerLockExample extends Application {
    public static final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    public static final Condition availableClick = lock.newCondition();
    public static int x, y;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws InterruptedException{
        Canvas can = new Canvas(128, 128);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(can));
        scene.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            lock.lock();
            try{
                x = (int) event.getSceneX();
                y = (int) event.getSceneY();
                availableClick.signal();
            }finally{
                lock.unlock();
            }
        });
        primaryStage.setTitle("Chess Game");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        lock.lock();
        try{
            availableClick.await();
            can.getGraphicsContext2D().setFill(Color.RED);
            can.getGraphicsContext2D().fillOval(x, y, 5, 5);
            System.out.printf("Click[x=%d ,y=%d]%n", x, y);
        }finally{
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: JavaFX runs on just one thread including all the click etc events that happens inside it. You should use conditions and locks only when mutliple threads want to interact with each other. In your case once await() is called JavaFX freezes and dosen't process any more events after that. You can just add/remove children from your scene based on click events rather than stalling for something to happen

Comment: @Syncit Well, that sucks, but thanks. Any specific reason you did not make that an answer?

Comment: because i just addressed the problem in your current approach but don't know an alternative that works for your specific problem.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? As pointed out in another comment, event handlers are invoked on the JavaFX Application Thread, so you could achieve the same thing simply by updating the canvas directly in the `onMouseClicked` handler.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you separate the UI, computer, and the player with multi threading.

JavaFX GUI will be frozen and could cause issues (such as listening for the click) if you are pausing its thread, so what I would do is create a thread for the computer player and a thread for the actual player. This way you can lock/unlock those threads as you wish and the GUI will not be frozen.

To implement multi threading you can use the following code :

```
private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExS;
private ScheduledFuture<?>       scheduled;
/* Start thread to periodically execute getData() with 0ms starting delay every 500ms  */
scheduledExS = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduled    = scheduledExS.scheduleAtFixedRate(getData, 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
/* Stop thread when finished */
scheduledExS.shutdownNow();
```

where `getData` is a runnable function

```
Runnable getData = () -> { /* Do something */ };
```